# How to extract tuple from a datatype?

Tags: functional-programming, sml

New to SML and trying to learn through a series of exercises. The function I am trying to write deals with flattening a tree with N children. My approach was to simply take the current `NTreeNode` and add its value to some list that I would return. Then take its second argument, the list of children, and tack that on to another list, which would be my queue. This queue would serve as all the items I still have left to process.

I tried to do this approach by passing the `NTreeList` and the list I would return with the initial value in `flattenNTree`, to a helper function.

However, when I try to process an `NTreeNode` from my queue it gives me back an `NTree` and I can't use my `first`/`second` functions on that, I need a tuple back from the queue. I just don't understand how to get back a tuple, I tried to use the `NTreeNode` constructor, but even that's giving me an `NTree` back.

My question is how can I extract a tuple from the `NTree` datatype I have defined.

```
datatype NTree =
NTreeNode of int * NTree list
| EmptyNTree
;

fun first  (a, _) = a;
fun second (_, b) = b;

fun processTree queue finalList  = 
  if null queue
   then finalList
  else processTree ((tl queue)@(second(NTreeNode(hd queue)))) finalList@[first (NTreeNode (hd queue)) ]
;
fun flattenNTree EmptyNTree = []
   | flattenNTree (NTreeNode x) = processTree (second x) [(first x)]
 ;
```

An example input value:

```
val t =
  NTreeNode (1, [
    NTreeNode (2, [
      NTreeNode (3, [EmptyNTree]),
      NTreeNode (4, []),
      NTreeNode (5, [EmptyNTree]),
      EmptyNTree
    ]),
    NTreeNode (6, [
      NTreeNode (7, [EmptyNTree])
    ])
  ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier to take things apart with pattern matching than fiddling around with selectors like `first` or `tl`.

It's also more efficient to accumulate a list in reverse and fix that when you're finished than to repeatedly append to the end of it.

```
fun processTree [] final = reverse final
  | processTree (EmptyTree::ts) final = processTree ts final
  | processTree ((NTreeNode (v,t))::ts) final = processTree (ts @ t) (v :: final)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `processTree` function is missing the case for `EmptyNTree` and you seem to be trying to add `NTree` constructors before calling `first` and `second`, whereas you need rather to strip them away, as you do in `flattenNTree`.

Both problems can be fixed by applying pattern matching to the head of the queue:

```
fun processTree queue finalList =
  if null queue
  then finalList
  else case hd queue of
         EmptyNTree => processTree (tl queue) finalList
       | NTreeNode v => processTree (tl queue @ second v) (finalList @ [first v])
;
```

You might also consider an implementation based on list functionals (although the order of the result is not the same):

```
fun flattenNTree t = case t of
    EmptyNTree => []
  | NTreeNode (n, nts) => n :: (List.concat (List.map flattenNTree nts));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the tree type

```
datatype 'a tree = Node of 'a * 'a tree list
                 | Leaf
```

you can fold it:

```
fun fold f e0 Leaf = e0
  | fold f e0 (Node (x, ts)) =
    let val e1 = f (x, e0)
    in foldl (fn (t, e2) => fold f e2 t) e1 ts
    end
```

and flatten it:

```
fun flatten t =
    fold op:: [] t
```